# HV021 postgresql что-то пошло не так

Tags: postgresql, count

Есть обёртки сторонних данных таблица ora в ней одна колонка start.
При запросе `select * from ora` выводит значения которые там имеются, а вот при запросе `select count(*) from ora` выводит ошибочку

```
ERROR: Table definition mismatch: Foreign source returned 1 column(s), but query expected 0 column(s)
SQL-состояние: HV021
```

Кто понимает что происходит, пожалуйста объясните.
P.S. данные в таблице есть, там их 5-6 строк.

Comment: Хм при запросе select count(start) from ora всё работает,хм хм хм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно использовать
 `select count(start) from ora`